# Samsung Galaxy s2 DSR is ON. Don't sent DTR ON

Tags: android

When I plug my device to my computer I keep getting the following error in the LogCat:

```
07-12 15:23:57.695: E/DataRouter(1820): DSR is ON. Don't send DTR ON.
07-12 15:23:59.700: E/DataRouter(1820): usb connection is true
```

My OS is 4.0.3 GT-19100T.

I have seen posts about it but no answer. does any1 knows how to stop these annoying messages in my LogCat?

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you also have a problem using the DDMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can selectively disable logs from appearing. For example in your case, you can do

adb logcat DataRouter:S

If you want to completely disable logs

adb logcat -s

Comment: or if you are using eclipse, Uncheck the checkbox at  "Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Logcat -> Display logcat view...."

Answer (score 0):

This and a lot of others errors is a bug of firmware (or preinstalled application). You cannot do anything.
If you use Linux I suggest to use grep to filter this messages

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see just your app's log messages, use '-s' to filter out everything else and then specify your app's tag along with the lowest level of logging you want:
   adb logcat -s  MyApp:V       # show only MyApp, all logging levels
   adb logcat -s  MyApp:I       # show only MyApp, logging levels 'info' and above

To see the available filter letters, use
  adb logcat --help
They are (in order of precedence):

- F   fatal
- E   error
- W   warning
- I     info
- D   debug
- V   verbose

They correspond to using Log.d(...), Log.i(...), etc., in your app.